# It's strange. The home page of developer.salesforce.com is totally garbled

Tags: developer

It is not the first to see a garbled developer.salesforce.com.

It is so strange.

Only the home page of the developer site is so.

Is it some kind of browser issue?

[image]

Comment: Definitely a temp glitch or looks like some kind of JSON response, what did you hit?

Comment: Works fine for me :)

Comment: @NagendraSingh I just opened a browser and type "developer.salesforce.com" in the url. Then, I see the screen. I've tried both Chrome and Edge.

Comment: I've seen this question posted twice by others in SFSE before, but unable to find them now. I believe its got to be due to a temp glitch in either your network or browser.

Comment: To me it happens sometimes if the `https` is missing.